# How to load data into data base using dbunit in Maven

Tags: maven, dbunit

Below is my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <configuration>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</url>
    <username>usernamet</username>
    <password>password</password>
    <dataTypeFactoryName>org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlDataTypeFactory</dataTypeFactoryName>
    <metadataHandlerName>org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlMetadataHandler</metadataHandlerName>
    <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
    <src>target/dbunit/export.xml</src><!--compare 和 operation 要用到它 -->
    <type>CLEAN_INSERT</type><!--operation 要用到它-->
    </configuration>
    <executions> 
<execution> 
 <id>test-compile</id> 
<phase>test-compile</phase> 
 <goals> 
<goal>operation</goal> 
 </goals> 
 </execution> 
 <execution> 
<id>test</id> 
 <phase>test</phase> 
<goals> 
<goal>operation</goal> 
</goals> 
 </execution> 
 </executions> 
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I run mvn `dbunit:operation` on command line.

```
Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app
[INFO]    task-segment: [dbunit:operation]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dbunit:operation {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 10 23:02:41 PST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
```

It says build successful. But there is no data in the database.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDBUNIT-1)

If your data file is in flat format (FlatXmlDataSet), adding flat will perform the update.

For example:
This doesn't work:

> ```
>       <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>             <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>                     ...
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <phase>test-compile</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>operation</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <type>CLEAN_INSERT</type>
>                     <src>src/main/resources/opc1.xml</src>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
> ```

But this works (at least it did for me):

> ```
>       <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>             <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
>             <dependencies>
>                 <dependency>
>                     <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
>                     <artifactId>jConnect</artifactId>
>                     ...
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <phase>test-compile</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>operation</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                     <configuration>
>                             <format>flat</format>
>                         <type>CLEAN_INSERT</type>
>                     <src>src/main/resources/opc1.xml</src>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
> ```

Answer (score -1):

1. Create the database(schema) in respective user.
2. You should have the proper perperties files in XML form in the project.
3. Go to the project for and type the command e.g.
   `c:>project_name>mvn dbunit:operation`. This will add all the properties